# How to properly test promises

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have test in React app using Jest and React-testing-library:

```
it('promise test', () => {
    const promise = new Promise<string>(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve('foo'), 1000))
    expect.assertions(1);
    expect(promise).resolves.toBe('foo');
});
```

If i run test I get message:

```
Error: expect.assertions(1)
Expected :1
Actual   :0
```

My question is.. Why code in `expect(promise).resolves.toBe('foo')` is not called? How to test this async promise?

Comment: maybe `dataSources.use` is throwing an error and you are not catching it

Comment: It's not happening. I tried rewrite await Promise into `dataSources.use<string>('test').then(value => console.log('Value', value)).catch(reason => console.log('Reason', reason));` and still nothing

Comment: Can you try `expect(promise).to.be.resolvedWith('foo')` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct solution is: You must make anonymous function async and await on response.

```
it('promise test', async () => {
    const promise = new Promise<string>(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve('foo'), 1000))
    expect.assertions(1);
    await expect(promise).resolves.toBe('foo')
});
```

or this way

```
it('promise test', async () => {
    const promise = new Promise<string>(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve('foo'), 1000))
    expect.assertions(1);
    await promise;
    promise.then(value => {
        expect(value).toBe('foo');
    })
});
```